# Is it bad style to access AccountManager from Authenticator?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-authenticator

Is it bad style to access the Android `AccountManager` from my authenticator's `getAuthToken` method?

The reason I'm asking, I have two different token types, access and refresh tokens. Now if I try to get an access token and there is currently none, but a valid refresh token, my Authenticator should use that to obtain a new access token from the server. So far, I'm retrieving stored tokens from the account manager using `peekAuthToken`.

But it just seems rather "inverted" to call the account manager from within the authenticator. Also, it makes it very hard to write working test cases for it, since I can't test my class directly but have to manipulate state through the manager...with all its asynchronous callbacks and everything.